# python package import modules using __init__.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, package

I have made a package in the following structure:

```
test.py
pakcage1/
    __init__.py
    module1.py
    module2.py
```

In the `test.py` file, with the code

```
from package1 import *
```

what I want it to do is to

```
from numpy import *
from module1 import *
from module2 import *
```

**What should I write in `__init__.py` file to achieve this?**

Currently in my `__init__.py` file I have

```
from numpy import *
__all__ = ['module1','module2']
```

and this doesn't give me what I wanted. In this way numpy wan't imported at all, and the modules are imported as

```
import module1
```

rather than

```
from module1 import *
```

Comment: I don't see how having `from package1 import *` behave like `from numpy import *` would be of any good.

Comment: well I made this package for numerical simulation, so whenever I use this package, I will need numpy. That's why I want it there.

Comment: It is just that I don't like the idea of having an import obfuscating another one, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want this, your `__init__.py` should contain just what you want:

```
from numpy import *
from module1 import *
from module2 import *
```

When you do `from package import *`, it imports all names defined in the package's `__init__.py`.

Note that this could become awkward if there are name clashes among the modules you import.  If you just want convenient access to the functions in those modules, I would suggest using instead something like:

```
import numpy as np
import module1 as m1
import module2 as m2
```

That is, import the modules (not their contents), but under shorter names.  You can then still access numpy stuff with something like `np.add`, which adds only three characters of typing but guards against name clashes among different modules.

Answer (score 2):

I second BrenBarn's suggestion, but be warned though, importing everything into one single namespace using from x import * is generally a bad idea, unless you know for certain that there won't be any conflicting names.

I think it's still safer to use import package.module, though it does take extra keystrokes.